# Ошибка python: No module named 'stdio'

Tags: python, python-3.x

Опыта в python ноль, поэтому прошу подсказки. Установил Python 3.8. Стандартная установка для Windows 7. Каталог `c:\Programs\Python\Python38-32\`. Дальше пытаюсь запустить такой код:

```
import stdio

stdio.writeln('Hello, World')
```

На что получаю сообщение с ошибкой:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python\helloworld.py", line 1, in <module>
    import stdio
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'stdio'
```

Гугление показало, что python не видит модуль **stdio**. Проверил PATH — каталог установки указан.

Подскажите куда копать?

Comment: В python нет модуля stdio (по крайней мере стандартного). То что я нахожу (https://pypi.org/project/stdio/) вообще связано с сетью, судя по описанию.

Comment: в питоне такого модуля нет, можно установить дополнительно, но в нем нет функций `write` и т.д., а вам скорее всего нужно тогда `sys.stdin`, `sys.stdout`

Comment: Похоже вы смотрите примеры из этой книги: https://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/python/cover.png , и тогда вам нужно брать модули для этих примеров отсюда: https://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/python/code/

Comment: Вот оно в чём дело! Этот код из книжки учебного курса https://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/python/11hello/helloworld.py.html

Comment: *«The stdio.py file is one that we designed specifically for this book.»*  Я вам только могу рекомендовать прекратить читать эту странную книгу.

Answer (score -2):

```bash
pip install stdio
```

Если нет pip:

```bash
python -m pip install -U pip
```

Надеюсь, это поможет!

EDIT: Это версия подходит для Windows.

EDIT: Зачем использовать какой-то
несуществующий модуль, когда можно
использовать простой `print`?

```py
print('Hello, World')
# Здесь модули не нужны!
```

Comment: Это не тот stdio, читайте комментарии к вопросу

Comment: Я придумал самый короткий способ:
`from sys import stdin, stdout; #ваш код здесь`
Этот метод использует stdin и stdout.

Comment: Это не решает проблему отсутствующего модуля stdio

Comment: Я обновил ответ, можно проверять.

Comment: Вы комментарии к вопросу читали вообще? Желание дать ответ похвально, но всё-таки в данном случае проблема у человека совсем другая была. Да и вопрос старый и не актуальный.